# Cometd/Bayeux client in Android App

Tags: android, cometd, bayeux

Has anybody implemented a Cometd/Bayeux client in a native Android App?

I tried to use

```
org.cometd.java:cometd-java-client:3.0.3
```

but it uses jetty HttpClient which has dependencies to `java.lang.management.ManagementFactory` which is not available on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CometD 2.9.1 on Android. The protocol has not changed between CometD 2 and CometD 3, and you will have Android compatibility.